# Convert from list to values in R

Tags: r, lapply

In R I have a data.frame made up completely of factors.

I'd like to store each factor as a value, such that `v1 <- as.factor(factor.df$v1)` I'd like to apply this to each variable in the dataframe.

Using `variable_factors <- lapply(factors.df, as.factor)` returns a list whereas I need each value to be stored as it would under `v1 <- as.factor(factor.df$v1)`

I'm trying to convert these into a model.matrix in preparation for LASSO regression as found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72251/an-example-lasso-regression-using-glmnet-for-binary-outcome).

Any suggestions? I feel like I'm missing something small...

Comment: It's best practice to not assign each vector to the global environment. Lists are designed to hold them all. You can access each one with `variable_factors[[1]]` and so on.

Comment: I would retthink this... but `list2env(factor.df, envir = .GlobalEnv)` should work

Comment: I have to if I'm going to pass it the model.matrix argument, correct? [link] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72251/an-example-lasso-regression-using-glmnet-for-binary-outcome)

Comment: I think it may be worth updating your question describing what you are trying to do (rather than how), as this probably isnt the best approach.

Comment: okay, thanks for the update...you dont need individual vectors, you can pass the dataframe... so `model.matrix(~ -1 + . , data=factor.df, contrasts.arg = lapply(factor.df, contrasts, contrasts=FALSE))` will give all levels of each factor. (assumes the variables are all factors, so you will need to tweak this if some are continuous)

Comment: This works great! There is one problem, however. My factor.df has 24, 976 observations while the model.matrix only has 24,945. Any reason why that might be? My data does not have any `N/A's`

Comment: Nope dont know. sorry ... missing values are  the obvious culprit ; just to check `dim(factor.df)[1] == dim(na.omit(factor.df))[1]`. Did you have a look at a vanilla model.matrix call, in case the level argument is messing up things (although i dont see how it would mess up the rows), so `model.matrix(~ . , data=factor.df)`